# ¿Cómo alinear elementos en una CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo la siguiente tarjeta que quiero reutilizar en un RecyclerView, contiene una foto y debajo a la izquierda un botón y un nombre, a la derecha debe estar una imagen y un TextView, para esto use LinearLayouts para encerrar cada grupo de elementos y posicionarlos con la propiedad "layout_gravity" pero no logro alinearlos, la vista previa aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código XML de la tarjeta es el siguiente:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cvMascota"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radio"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bone_on"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_datos_arriba"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_bone_off"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/nombre_mascota"
                android:textSize="@dimen/nombre"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_nombre_derecha"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hueso_count"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Por más que en layout_gravity ponga "right" o "end" no se nota ningún cambio.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para posicionar el hueso y el TextView a la derecha de la tarjeta manteniendo la compatibilidad con pantallas diferentes (porque podría usar un margin o padding pero quiero alinearlo a la derecha de la pantalla sea del tamaño que sea)?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: haz un layout horizontal con matchparent que ocupe todo el hueco y ahí le pones gravitiy right (los elementos dentro de este se pondrán a su derecha)

Comment: @pcg26 ya lo intenté pero al poner right no hay ninguna diferencia, se mantiene a la izquierda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de muchos intentos fallidos con `android:layout_gravity="right"` encontré otra solución usando `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` mi código usando la primera opción es el siguiente, con este no logré alinear los elementos que quería:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cvMascota"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radio"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_entre_tarjetas"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/tarjeta"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bone_on"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/blanco"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_datos_arriba"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bone_off"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nombre_mascota"
            android:textSize="@dimen/nombre"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_nombre_derecha"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFavs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hueso_count"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFavs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_hueso_favs"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Ahora, mi código después de solucionar el problema quedó asi:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cvMascota"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radio"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_entre_tarjetas"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/tarjeta"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bone_on"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@color/blanco"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_datos_arriba"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPlus1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bone_off"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nombre_mascota"
            android:textSize="@dimen/nombre"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_nombre_derecha"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFavs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_hueso_favs"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFavs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hueso_count"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Como puede verse no hubo muchos cambios además de usar layoutDirection y de invertir el orden de mi TextView y del ImageView, los invertí porque al cambiar la dirección del layout los elementos se voltean, es decir, si primero tengo un ImageView y luego un TextView, después de aplicar la propiedad me aparecerá primero el TextView y luego el ImageView, es por esto que cambié el orden para que aparecieran correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

Un ejemplo:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo funciona perfectamente pero no se por qué cuando lo pongo en mi código no cambia nada, es extraño y la verdad no se qué estoy haciendo mal, sin embargo encontré otra manera de solucionarlo sin usar gravity, lo publicaré como respuesta para poner mi código. A pesar de que no haya funcionado  o yo no haya podido aplicarlo bien muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)